# Error con RealmSearchView con mi Base de Dato de Realm

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, realm

quiero implementar un SearchView en realm y me encontre con RealmSearchView en https://github.com/LNSD/RealmSearchView pero me da error en el adaptador esto son los errores

```
at com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Adapters.ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter$ExpedienteItemView.bind(ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.java:100)
                  at com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Adapters.ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.onBindRealmViewHolder(ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.java:70)
                  at com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Adapters.ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.onBindRealmViewHolder(ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.java:23)
```

en la linea 100 esta:

```
 public void bind(Expediente expediente, int index) {
        this.expediente = expediente;
        this.index = index;

        estac.setText(expediente.getEstacion());
        area.setText(expediente.getArea());
        estado.setText(expediente.getEstado());

    }
```

en la linea 70:

```
@Override
public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final Expediente expediente = realmResults.get(position);
    viewHolder.container.bind(expediente, position);
}
```

y por ultimo en la 23 incluye mi adaptador completo que es este:

```js
package com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Buscar;
import com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Models.Expediente;
import com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.R;

import co.moonmonkeylabs.realmsearchview.RealmSearchAdapter;
import co.moonmonkeylabs.realmsearchview.RealmSearchViewHolder;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

/**
 * Created by yeikel on 05/11/2017.
 */

public class ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter extends RealmSearchAdapter < Expediente,
  ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.ViewHolder > {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter(
      Context context,
      Realm realmResults,
      String filterColumnName) {
      super(context, realmResults, filterColumnName);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RealmSearchViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
      ExpedienteItemView container;
      OnItemClickListener mListener;

      public ViewHolder(ExpedienteItemView container, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(container);
        this.container = container;
        this.mListener = listener;

        container.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
          mListener.onItemClick(container, container.getExpediente(), container.getIndex());
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateRealmViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
      return new ViewHolder(new ExpedienteItemView(viewGroup.getContext()), this.listener);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
      final Expediente expediente = realmResults.get(position);
      viewHolder.container.bind(expediente, position);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
      void onItemClick(View view, Expediente expediente, int index);
    }

    private class ExpedienteItemView extends RelativeLayout {

      TextView estac = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEstac);
      TextView area = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvArea);
      TextView estado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEstado);

      private Expediente expediente;
      private int index;

      public ExpedienteItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
      }

      private void init(Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.plantilla_recycler_item, this);

      }

      public void bind(Expediente expediente, int index) {
        this.expediente = expediente;
        this.index = index;

        estac.setText(expediente.getEstacion());
        area.setText(expediente.getArea());
        estado.setText(expediente.getEstado());

      }

      public Expediente getExpediente() {
        return expediente;
      }

      public int getIndex() {
        return index;
      }
    }

  }
```

y este es el error completo que me sale:

```css
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasiocos, PID: 2208
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Adapters.ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter$ExpedienteItemView.bind(ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.java:100)
                      at com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Adapters.ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.onBindRealmViewHolder(ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.java:70)
                      at com.condado.yeikel.mediosbasicos.Adapters.ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.onBindRealmViewHolder(ExpedienteSearchViewAdapter.java:23)
                      at io.realm.RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:278)
                      at io.realm.RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java:49)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6067)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6100)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5282)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3379)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3188)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3632)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                      at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:630)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                      at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1367)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:849)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                   at android.widget.FrameLayou
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2208 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Porque creas la clase `ExpedienteItemView`?  Lo que haces en esa clase lo puedes hacer directamente en la clase `ViewHolder` y ahórrate unos cuantos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: ya encontre el problema es que en el ejemplo estaban implementando ButterKnife y se necesita especificamente para el metodo `bind` y en `onBindRealmViewHolder` ya que son metodos especiles que trabajan solamente con Realm

Comment: agrega tu solución como una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontre el problema es que en el ejemplo estaban implementando ButterKnife y se necesita especificamente para el metodo bind y en onBindRealmViewHolder ya que son metodos especiles que trabajan solamente con Realm